# Compacting soil after removing fence posts to install new posts with vibratory ram?

Tags: fence, landscaping, soil

I have a 6 foot wooden privacy fence I am looking to replace. Several of the posts are rotting right at ground level so their concrete footings are going to have to go.

A company sells a metal fencepost that is meant to be hidden and present the appearance of a wooden fence, which is desirable to me. I am thinking of using them as the metal should outlast any wood.

Rather than installing new concrete footings, I see a popular and cost effective method of installing fenceposts nowadays is with a vibratory driver that hammers the fenceposts right into the ground. Since I'll likely use a skid-steer to rip the old footings out, I can get an attachment that can drive in replacement posts. Put 4+ feet of post in the ground and 6' above and the fence should be solid.

The only question is how to prepare the soil. Ripping out the footings is going to leave holes that need to be filled. What steps should I take to compact or stabilize the soil, so that it can properly hold the posts? Would a plate compactor or jumping jack compactor be a good idea, or something else?

Or, should I just abandon this idea altogether and pour new footings for the new posts?

I live in Minnesota, with serious winters, and pretty loamy easily drained soil, so whatever I do it needs to withstand frost heave. Some of the current posts are not doing well at that.

Comment: Wow! Four feet in the ground! Maybe that is what is needed in MN. What is this fence going to hold, a 2000-lb Holstein bull? (What company sells these posts and how much are they?)

Comment: @JimStewart: I don't know if that's totally necessary, but I've always seen the 2:1 rule, so going 4 feet to be on the safe side seems like "might as well" to me, especially if I use a machine to install them. Build once ache once. This is for a city yard so no crazy bulls :) The posts are Master Halco postmasters, I've seen them in 10' lengths. I don't remember how much they cost but it was less than double a comparable PT 4x4.

Comment: I second what Jim said - 4 feet is a good bit excessive. I would personally do something like 16-24 inches for a home fence.

Comment: @cutrightjm: ok, well, regardless what the ideal depth is, that's not the point of the question, how to prepare the soil is.

Comment: In Dallas TX 8 ft long 4 x 4" pressure treated posts are adequate for a 6 ft fence. Thirty-five years ago when I replaced some of the original 4 x 4" cedar posts (termite eaten, rotted) with pressure treated I used a heavy digging bar and a standard hand post hole digger to clean out the holes, put soil in and tamped manually with the tamping pad of a heavy metal bar. That is, no concrete. But here we have soft limestone 18" below grade in some places. This is the so called Austin Chalk. I would be interested in seeing if this vibratory pile driver could drive fence posts through that.

Comment: Looks like Home Depot envisions using 7 ft 6 in master halco postmasters for up to a 6 ft fence. I see big problems if you would try to use the 10 ft length. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Halco-7-ft-6-in-Postmaster-633663/202091158?cm_mmc=SEM%7cTHD%7cgoogle%7c&mid=s%7cdc_mtid_8903rn225192_pcrid_254340303794_pkw__pmt_b_product__slid_&gclid=CjwKCAjww6XXBRByEiwAM-ZUIN9Zb6cLwvakNSYoBbQ_M7aLamIWcO27Ujq27r_oXq1NH-b_c6vtHxoCdGMQAvD_BwE&dclid=CMey8IrJ5toCFUHCwAodMGoElA

Comment: The City of Dallas originally used a product like the Halco postmaster for mounting signs in city parks. There are some which must be 50 years old in the park near us looking as good as new. The currently used mounting posts are much lighter duty and have a square cross section. Probably the Halco Postmaster was simply heavier than needed for signs. I would also think that a person (think kid) running into one would have a significantly higher risk of injury than the rounded corner square profile steel post Dallas uses now. As a fence post the Postmaster doesn't have that problem.

Comment: The picture in the Home Depot entry on the Master Halco Postmaster 7'6" fence post shows an installation in which the metal post is very cleverly covered by wood. This should make a very attractive fence. The current standard in Dallas is ~ 2-3/8" diameter circular cross section tubular galvanized steel posts. The normal installation is to employ brackets to attach the rails. There are several types of brackets available, all of them unattractive to a greater or less extent. A common bracket type presents a risk of paw injury to a dog jumping against it or to a person falling against it.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/138262/46271.   Related

Answer (score 2):

Cut off old posts slightly below grade.

Leave concrete footing in place.
 Drive in new posts 4feet deep into ground at a short distance to the left or right of old post. Driving in that deep would mean no footing necessary. Leaving the old post base and concrete would eliminate need to compact.  Enjoy your new fence. Thanks for asking here because now I know about these posts and will use them on my fence redo.