# Cement Recommendations for Fence Posts

Tags: concrete, fence, post, cement

I am planning to event a fence this summer and, given the size of ~ 250 linear feet, am looking for the cheapest option for cementing the poles. I am considering the use of metal Postmaster ([MasterHalco](http://www.postmasterfence.com/)) posts and plan to set them 4' in the ground in ~ 8' holes as I am up north and the frost line is ~3.5 feet.
[image]

I have checked out multiple types of fast dry concrete specifically designed for fence post but would like to find a cheaper option. Is a standard portland concrete mix acceptable for this application? If Yes, what ratios of cement/sand/gravel should be used?

Also, are sonotubes recommended?

Thanks

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/138233/46271.  Related

Comment: Drive them in with a vibrating ram no need fir concrete

Answer (score 1):

If you are going that deep in the ground, your fence posts will be plenty stable by placing and packing the dirt back around them. To pack the dirt I use a 2X4 with the end cut down to size and rounded for a better feel as a handle, and for tighter places I use a 1X4. I would only do concrete around them if you are setting a large gate to a post.

If you must use portland, instead of the just add water type, the mix ratio is 1-2-3. 1 shovel portland, 2 shovels sand, 3 shovels gravel.

Comment: I add a little Portland cement to sackcrete for a large gate and it works fine, smaller or light weight I just use the bag.